# App uninstalled feedback from GCM / APN

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

We are planing to have push notifications enabled in our Android and IOS app. So while noting down the scenarios we came across one question :

Do we get a feedback from the cloud services (GCM and APN) that app is uninstalled for a given payload?

Answer (score 5):

I am answering about GCM

> When users uninstall an application, it is not automatically
>   unregistered on GCM. It is only unregistered when the GCM server tries
>   to send a message to the device and the device answers that the
>   application is uninstalled or it does not have a broadcast receiver
>   configured to receive `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` intents.
>   At that point, your server should mark the device as unregistered (the
>   server will receive a [NotRegistered](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#unreg_device) error).

More info at :- [GCM Architectural Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

Answer (score 1):

Pankaj's answer regarding GCM is correct.

As for APNS,  they have a [feedback service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) in which they return device tokens of devices that uninstalled the app.